# ADO.NET How to keep my connection Active

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I have created a windows service using c#.NET,  The service will updated oracle tables whenever it receives new files. I have kept timer control and the time limit as 30 seconds. I am using ODP.NET as data access layer.

The very first time I will get error, but subsequently the service will work fine. If service is Idle for a long time if it receives a file, I will get "connection lost error", but after if we receives file it will loaded successfully.

Kindly suggest me do I need add any properties in connection string to fix this error?

Comment: Why not just use connection pooling, and open/close in your code? Keeping connections open for an infinite amount of time is going to be problematic.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this? We're missing significant information that would make it possible to answer this question. Post the code! I suspect you're trying to hold a DB connection open, instead of creating a new connection for each file, as you should with .Net, but without code it's impossible to know anything for sure, and difficult to provide good examples for how to fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe the connection is closed by some firewalls or proxy server or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Karthik Two issues here it seems.

1. You are best to open and close a new connection each time your service is called.

   2. Windows services quickly go to a latent state if not called and they will respond slower on the next call. If the caller does not have a sufficient timeout value to accomodate this lag then it will return a time out error. If you address these two points you should be fine.